# Installing php and mysql for Joomla - Can't get past installation

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, installation

Trying to install Joomla 2.5.7 but I can't get past the Pre-Installation Check as it says: `Database support: No`

I've got mysql (5.5.24) and php (5.3.15) installed manually on a Linux machine (I don't want to use LAMPP). I've done this a few times before and checked everything is the same with my other working machines in terms of the packages and the php.ini file. I can also access the mysql fine.

Any suggestions on what I can try? Is there a way to find out what check it is failing on?

Comment: I have the exact MySQL version and PHP 5.3.13 on WAMP and everything installs fine for me. I might have been something you did wrong when installing MySQL on your server.

Comment: @Lodder Thanks for the response. I've tried everything and I'm out of options =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh! I did miss a package. A pretty vital one at that: `php-mysql`. Don't forget to restart web server.

Answer (score 0):

Most CMS come with a sql database setup files. These files must be added to your mysql data. Or tables and users must be manually created.
Have you done this?? If not check manual for details.

http://linuxinternetworks.com/how-to-install-joomla-in-linux/

Comment, after trying, I am reading it too.

Comment: Joomla does come with database setup files, they get added upon installation which is what the OP is trying to do but can't. No tables should be manually created with Joomla

Comment: then we have a problem. No Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla checks what databases are supported by testing each type for a connection. One possible  issue is that the way you have things set up the owner of the installation process  does not have permission to use the databases.

Ooops sorry I didn't see that you had soled